# Why is HSO4- shown as an example of a weak acid instead of HSO4?

Tags: acid-base

I'm watching some (really awesome) chemistry courses, and I think I have a fairly decent handle on acids and bases (or maybe not, and I'm fooling myself). But the teacher just showed a table of weak/strong acids. $\ce{HSO4-}$  was one of them.

I'm wondering, why hydrogen sulfate *ion* instead of just hydrogen sulfate? Why is $\ce{HSO4-}$ an acid and $\ce{HSO4}$ apparently isn't? This was the only ion on the table. Or does $\ce{HSO4}$ simply not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bisulfate molecule doesn't exist in solution. I can only find references to the hydrogen sulfate molecule as part of salts, which implies that hydrogen sulfate is usually found as an ion.

The bisulfate (hydrogen sulfate) ion is indeed an acid. It is a relatively strong weak acid too, with a $\ce{K_a}$ value of $1.2 * 10^{-2}$.

Part of the reason for its acidity has to do with its electronegative oxygens isolationg electron density away from the hydrogen atom bonded to the oxygen. This makes the hydrogen more partially positive and thus more reactive (more likely to be taken by a base).

[image]

Comment: I have to add, that while $\ce{HSO4}$ does not exist, the doubled molecule $\ce{H2S2O8}$ (peroxodisulfuric acid) does exist and is apparently a quite strong acid (its double ammonium salt is stable solid)

Comment: I have to add, that $\ce{HSO4}$ might well exist, just not in aqueous solution - in the gas phase, why not ?

Comment: I agree Martin!

Comment: @Martin - it would have an odd number of valence electrons, and so it probably wouldn't exist for long!

Comment: _"Part of the reason for its acidity has to do with its electronegative oxygens isolationg electron density away from the hydrogen atom bonded to the oxygen. "_ is that actually true? How would that work? Isn't it just acidic because the negative charge can be fairly good delocalized into the $\pi$-bonds? If we'd were to replace one of the two  S-O double bond with a SOH group, I think it would be that acidic anymore...

Comment: It is true. Do you think a hydroxide ion with its significant negative charge density would be more likely to attack a hydrogen atom with no partial charge or a hydrogen atom with a partial positive charge? Your reason is also true. The sulfate anion has several resonance structures.

Comment: @Jori there is no significant pi bonding in the sulfate anion. I think that was discussed with the phosphate ion here on the site. I am on mobile now, so it is hard to find the reference. However, the electron of hydrogen is already very much localised at the oxygen. The hydrogen oxygen bond is quite ionic.

Comment: @thomij Agreed, but it would certainly exist longer than an anion in the gasphase.

Comment: _" I think it wouldn't be that acidic anymore..."_ is what I meant to say. Do these structures exist? Replacing one double S-O bond with a SOH group. I think you understood me wrong. I meant that the reason sulfuric acid is so acidic, is not the amount of oxygen atoms close to the SOH group, but the delocalisation of the negative charge when hydrogen takes off. Resulting in a more stable structure. Is the force of the other surrounding oxygen atoms (that are negatively charged) of suck influence over that distance, and wouldn't the strongly positively charged sulfur get in the way?

Comment: I'm just thinking here a bit. You guys are probably way better educated than me in chemistry haha. We coudl confirm the truth (or at least get an indication of the truth) if we knew the acidity of the hypothetical structures H3SO4 and H4SO4 (do they even exist?)

Answer (score 4):

I notice that there is no mention of [polyprotic acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid#Polyprotic_acids) in the other answers!

$\ce{H2SO4}$ ([sulfuric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid)) is diprotic - meaning it has two "detachable" protons which can come off in aqueous solution. The first one is strongly acidic - the $Ka = 2.4 × 10^6$ - this means the odds of finding a non-dissociated $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecule in solution are something like 1 out of 2.4 million.

On the other hand, the second proton is *weakly acidic* - the $Ka = 1.0 × 10^{-2}$. This means that there will mostly be $\ce{HSO4-}$ instead of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ in solution (roughly 100 times as much).

The other answers are correct in saying that $\ce{HSO4}$ does not exist in solution - but it is important to realize that we list the bisulfate ion ($\ce{HSO4-}$) as a weak acid because it is the [conjugate base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_base) of sulfuric acid, and is in turn the conjugate acid of the sulfate ion. This becomes very important when you start to study acid/base equilibria.

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{HSO4}$ does not exist.  There is $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HSO4-}$  Try drawing the Lewis structure for sulfate ion.  You'll see that there are two oxygens with formal charges.  They can be left as is or they can have $\ce{H}$ bonded to them.

Comment: I think you mean H- bonded to them (H forms single bonds).

Comment: The adequate Lewis structure for the sulfate ion has one negative charge at each oxygen and a double positive charge at sulfur. Everything else is just too far from the truth.